weird fold in model
hi I'm getting this weird fold in my model and I don't know how to fix it. any suggestions? i only have subdivide and bevel on my model 

here is the file 

can you share blend file?

Please share your Blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

The outer face is what's called an 'n-gon'

i added the file

As mention in the comments you should replace the n-gon sides with quad mesh.

Start by deleting the bottom face of the model.
Select the top outer edges and extrude downwards.
With the bottom edge still selected flatten  them by scaling along the Z axis to zero. S Z 0
Straighten the lower edges by aligning vertices to either X or Y axis. S X 0 or S Y 0.
Select and scale the lower edge ring of vertices vertices inwards a little.
And finally add a few edge loops to the sides of the model, Ctrl R scroll MMB.



There are two big issues that contribute.

One is that you generally want faces to be a "quad", which means the face only has four vertices/edges. The sides of your chair have 7 per face (and the faces are concave, on top of that), so even though you want that face to be flat all across it, you'll still need to divide it into more faces, and make sure the faces are quads.

Second, when you want to smooth over a hard corner, you should bevel  the actual mesh at the corner (not as a modifier), which is basically making a second set of vertices very close to the vertices on the hard corners, on each side. Smoothing an edge that's more than 90 degrees tends to make weird things happen.


